# Make phone unzoom on button click

Tags: html, css, mobile

So there is a button on my site which comes after some text field,so I want it where when this button is pressed I want it to zoom out, as the content that comes after you click the button is best viewed unzoomed.

Here is the code for the button:

```
<footer>
    <button type="submit" onsubmit="return false;" class="button"><span style="font-family:clash; font-size:18px; color:#FFF; text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;">Generate</span></button>
    <b><font color="#ff6000">Tool Update: <span id="date4">02/25/2015</span></font></b>
    <br>
    <b>
    <div id="da-count">
        <font color="#ff6000">The total resources generated today: <span id="da-remain">754315144</span></font>
    </div>
    </b>
    <script>
        function daCounter (sum) {
            var daRemain = $("#da-remain");
                daCurrent = parseInt(daRemain.text()),
                daLeft = parseInt(sum),
                daSplit = daCurrent + daLeft;
            var daCount = setInterval(function () {
                daRemain.html(daCurrent + 1);
                daCurrent += 1;
                if (daCurrent == daSplit) clearInterval(daCount);
            }, 50);
        }
        // Trigger function after 600 milliseconds
        setTimeout(function () {
            daCounter(9999528823560);
        }, 600);
    </script>
    <b><font color="#ff6000">Users Online: 635</font></b>
    </footer>
```

So how can I make it so that once they click that button their phones screen unzooms. Would really appreciate some help thank you!

Comment: When you want to zoom out, was it ever zoomed in?

Comment: well before the button there are fields to fill in, so the phone zooms in automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What about to disable zoom on mobile? Would be this a option for you?

You could use this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

This should disable zooming on mobile device.

Comment: I want it to zoom in when they type but when they press the button I want it to unzoom